# NGINX + Wordpress gives ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, nginx, fastcgi

I have been trying to host a simple Wordpress blog using NGINX as the web-server. The blog is hosted as a subdirectory under domain_name.com/blog.

The main blog opens up correctly. But when trying to open the wp-admin under domain_name.com/blog/wp-admin my browser shows ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I am not sure if this is an issue with my NGINX configuration or wordpress configuration. Following is my NGINX server block:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name <domain_name.com>;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;

  location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass php;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

Wordpress is installed under the /var/www/html/blog directory. And the values for "siteurl" and "home" wp_options in the database are both pointing to domain_name.com/blog.

What would be a good way to solve this problem?

Additional notes that might be helpful:
When I try to access static files under the wp-content directory, they open without any issues. No redirection errors there.

Comment: Is this website only running `http`, or do you have `https` termination in front of it?

Comment: Oh yes, I somehow forgot to include that piece of information. My main server has https enabled, which then proxies the request to this server over normal http. Could that be an issue somehow?

Answer (score 7):

It is usual for WordPress to redirect an `http` session to `https` whenever accessing `wp-admin`. This may be controlled using the `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` and `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` settings in `wp-config.php`.

When a reverse proxy is terminating SSL, the fact that the originating connection is over `https` must be conveyed to WordPress to avoid a redirection loop.

Your reverse proxy should be setting headers such as `X-Forwarded-Proto`.

You need to change your `nginx` configuration so that the `HTTPS` flag is set correctly for WordPress.

For example:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $https_flag {
    default off;
    https on;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        fastcgi_param HTTPS $https_flag;
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked out perfectly. Not conveying SSL termination info to the second server was causing this issue. Thank you so much for the help.